# sort every line that does not match a pattern in vi

Tags: sorting, pattern-matching, vi

how can you sort in vi(m) every line that contains not a pattern.
Example: sort every line that does not start with #

I've tried 1,$v/^#/sort... without result!

Comment: how do you want it sorted compared to rest of the file?

Comment: it should be at the beginning of the file.

Comment: would a bash one-liner be sufficient instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it in multiple steps (assuming you need the sorted input at top):

1. Mark the 1st line.

   > `:1ka`
2. Move lines that does not match the pattern to top (replace with correct pattern).

   > `:v/^#/m0`
3. Sort the range that does not match the pattern.

   > `:1,'a sort`